# Correct way to use Toolbar Listener

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Hello I can't found an answer to my question. I am using a Toolbar, so I create it in OnCreate like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Toolbar");
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_examen);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

But I noticed that if I use a lot of options my OnCreate becomes very mesy. I love order so I made this listener out of OnCreate:

```
Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener toolbarListener = new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.opcion1:
                    Toast.makeText(ExamenActivity.this,"Opcion 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

And then on my OnCreate the toolbar is:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Quitar esta wea");
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_examen);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(toolbarListener);
```

This is working but Is this correct? Does this have a name? Thank you. I know it is a simple question but I want to it right

Comment: The both way is right. But you may choose your way of implementation according to your requirement.

Comment: Ok  ok, but is there any link for more info about this? Can I do this with all kind of listeners ?

Comment: The best way to find right solution in android documentation. You will find various way of implementing listeners in android. Please follow the link for more information https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea that is better, you can do it even better without extra variable as in

```
class YourActivity extends Activity implements Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener{

onCreate(){
      ...
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      toolbar.setTitle("Quitar esta wea");
      toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_examen);
      toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
      ...
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.opcion1:
                    Toast.makeText(ExamenActivity.this,"Opcion 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Great!! Can I use as many listener implement as I need? For example for button, touch , ?

Comment: Yes, multiple interfaces can be implemented in same class

Comment: Thank you !! Have a nice day!